# Segmentation Fault in a brief amount of code

Tags: c

I was trying something but come up with this little obstacle. Why do I get segault in this occasion ?

```
int main()
{
    int col_num,row_num=0;
    FILE *f = fopen("db.csv", "w+");

    int row_max = 10000;        
    int col_max = 10000;

    !!!row_num & col_num is determined due to time!!!

    int end_matrix[row_num][col_num];
    for(int row=0;row!=row_max;row++){
        for(int column=0;column!=col_max;column++){
            end_matrix[row][column] = row*column;    
        }  
        fprintf(f,"\n");
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: What are `row_max` and `col_max`?

Comment: The value of `col_num` is indeterminate (and could be seen as random or garbage). The value of `row_num` is zero. What makes you think those would be good values for array dimensions?

Comment: I added row and col_max definitions. Compilation completes perfectly but when I execute I get the segfault.

Comment: Now you have another problem: Arithmetic signed integer overflow. It's still possible to find systems where `int` is 16 bits, but almost universally `int` is 32 bits, which means it will hold values between around minus 2 billion to plus 2 billion. Your calculation `row * column` will overflow that, which leads to (even more!) *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Not to mention that the program doesn't make much sense. All it really would have done (if it otherwise worked) would be to write 10000 empty lines to the file. I think it's time you did some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of your program.

Comment: that's correct but I thought you figured out that end_matrix can be written to a file as well and the result would be squares, not empty lines ?

Comment: *Can* be written, and *is* written are two very different things. And you don't need the arrays for that. In fact, it's the arrays that cause problems for you (see my first comment). If all you want to do is to write the result of `row*column` to the file then just do it, skip the whole array.

Comment: thanks for the input. I am searching for the origin of the segmentation fault here for educational purposes.

Comment: Then see my first comment about the values of `col_num` and `row_num`.

Comment: Just not to pollute around I posted a section of the code where segfault is introduced from. Now edited again...

Comment: You should have started with an [mcve] properly! We should not have to drag bit by bit out you like this, also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Next time please try to write a better question right from the start.

Comment: Last possible problem: Local variables, including arrays (and variable-length arrays) are usually stored on the stack. The stack is a limited resource, on Windows the default stack per process is only a single MiB. If you loop `10000 * 10000` times, that means the memory for your array will be close to 10 ***giga*** bytes.

Comment: does not matter even if I assign "static int end_matrix[1000][1000]" ?

Comment: Use fixed-width integers like `int32_t col` and then you need `int64_t end_matrix[row_num][col_num]`, so than no overflow occurs (and cast before the multiplication). You just need `#include <stdint.h>`

Comment: What if the size of the matrix is variable throughout the code ? I tried int64_t but still I get the segfault.

Comment: `static int end_matrix[1000][1000];` should not crash your program. Unless you still keep writing to ten billion values. Without an [mcve] that replicates your problem, and that can be [debugged](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), there's no real help we can give you.

Comment: Did you check that `f` is not `NULL`?

Comment: You may also be creating an array bigger than what your compiler is allowing you. If you are using GCC, this option may help you: `-mcmodel=medium`

Comment: To check where exactly the segfault is happening, I usually put a `printf("DBG: %i\n", __LINE__); getchar();` in each point that could trigger the segfault, and you can then clearly see in which line it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the C99 variable length array feature to define the size of `end_matrix`. Unfortunately, `row_num` and `col_num` are both zero, meaning neither "dimension" has any storage allocated. When you attempt to write into the array, because no storage was reserved for it, you are writing past the end and triggering undefined behavior that is manifesting as a segfault.

It looks like you have `row_max` and `col_max` defined as constants; perhaps you meant to use those instead of `row_num` and `col_num` when defining `end_matrix`.

Comment: I added the necessary content.